inputExcludes was removed in a previous update, how do I use it now?
React-Native used to have an inputExcludes option in the projext.ext.react {} config options in it's build.gradle. But was removed in a later RN version (commit).
I am in the process of upgrading out applications RN version and wondering how can I still use inputExcludes.
I've tried adding it to the new react{} struct but I get errors that inputExcludes is not a support type of those configs.
